# operator-sdk support generate dependencies

Tags: operator-sdk, operator-lifecycle-manager

I am developing go-operator based on OLM. Now I need to generate the `dependencies.yaml` file in the `bundle/metadata` from the [Dependency Resolution document](https://olm.operatorframework.io/docs/concepts/olm-architecture/dependency-resolution/#generic-constraint) and [Operator Bundle](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-registry/blob/master/docs/design/operator-bundle.md#operator-bundle) in OLM and define the operator dependency. But I found nothing describing how to generate dependencies using operator. As I understand it, I need to manually write a complete dependency file in the metadata directory. The bundle directory is automatically generated by `operator-sdk generate bundle`, so I don't think it makes sense.

I wonder if there is another way to configure operator's dependencies. Or there is no documentation for a complete example

Do I want someone to tell me if a dependency file `dependencies.yaml` for an operator is manually created in the `bundle/metadata` directory? Or it's a creation that I can manifest in the config directory like `config/manifests`.

**env**

operator-sdk version:

`operator-sdk version: "v1.31.0", commit: "e67da35ef4fff3e471a208904b2a142b27ae32b1", kubernetes version: "v1.26.0", go version: "go1.20.6", GOOS: "darwin", GOARCH: "arm64"`

go version:

`go version go1.20.7 darwin/arm64`

kubectl version:

`Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"27", GitVersion:"v1.27.4+k3s1", GitCommit:"36645e7311e9bdbbf2adb79ecd8bd68556bc86f6", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-07-28T09:46:05Z", GoVersion:"go1.20.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/arm64"}`